# Is it normal that my vuex store module has a different vue instance than my normal components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In my vuex store component "Cars", I do `console.log(this._vm.$root)`, which yields:

```
Object { 
    _uid: 1, 
    _isVue: true, 
    "$options": {…}, 
    _renderProxy: Proxy, 
    _self: {…}, 
    "$parent": undefined, 
    "$root": {…}, 
    "$children": [], 
    "$refs": {}, 
    _watcher: null,
    … 
}
```

In any component, I can do `console.log(this.$root)`, which yields:

```
Object { 
    _uid: 3, 
    _isVue: true, 
    "$options": {…}, 
    _renderProxy: Proxy, 
    _self: {…}, 
    "$parent": undefined, 
    "$root": {…}, 
    "$children": (1) […], 
    "$refs": {}, 
    _watcher: {…},
     … 
}
```

Is this normal? As far as I know, I don't have two Vue instances in my app...

EDIT:

If I declare a data object for my main vue instance like this:

```
new Vue({
  store,
  data: {
    loading: false
  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

How can I access my loading variable in a vuex store component? In my components, the loading variable is there, but not in any of my store modules, since, like I just learned, vuex uses it's own vue instance...

Comment: Yes, it is normal. Internally Vuex uses its own Vue instance so that it can use the Vue reactivity system. `state` is mapped onto `data`, `getters` are mapped onto `computed` properties. I suggest studying the source code if you want to know more about how it works. Note that the underscore at the start of `_vm` is Vue's way of marking a property as private, so it isn't something you need to worry about unless you're trying to understand the internals.

Comment: Thanks, I already suspected something among those lines. I have a little followup in my edit above, would you care to check it out?

Comment: The components can see the store but not the other way around. If you need access to `loading` from inside the store then you should move it into your store's `state` rather than holding it in component `data`.

Comment: I did what you said and it worked perfectly!